# How to avoid conflict between a function and single posts

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

I'm using the following function to change display order of my posts:

```
function wpse139657_orderby($query){ 

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'book_release_date' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );

        if (is_admin() || $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'book') return $query;
} 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');
```

...but it looks like it is creating a conflict with the single posts, in fact the following query stopped working just after I added the above function into my blog...

```
$images = get_attached_media('image');
$featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    unset($images[ $featured_image_id ] );
}
$ximage =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( key($images),'medium');
echo '<img src="' . $ximage[0] . '">';
```

Is there any way to edit the first code above (function) and set it up not to interfere with single post pages?

Answer (score 2):

this is simple to check before set query parameters.

```
function wpse139657_orderby($query){
    if(is_single && !is_singular('book')){
        return;
    } 
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'book_release_date' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );

        if (is_admin() || $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'book') return $query;
} 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');
```

Comment: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 14 of file wp-content/themes/MyTheme/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: Oh well it was     if(is_single && !is_singular('book')){ you forgot to close it. BTW unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Single post pages still get the conflict, and the second code shown in my question (the one to retrieve an image) does not work not even using your code.